# integrate Firebase with cocos2dx

Tags: firebase, cocos2d-x, firebase-authentication

I have one game built using cocos2dx game engine, and I want to use Firebase features (Authentication using Google and Facebook), can you help me to select the best way to integrate with Firebase.

I tried using C++ sdk, but I had many issues. Then I tried to integrate it using Java code in the Android version, and it was working, but in the iOS version, I have issues.

Please your help to do it in iOS or use C++ sdk
Thanks

Comment: You mention that you have issues integrating with iOS, what kind of issues are you experiencing?  I'm not really sure what this question is asking.

Comment: I find issues in importing the sdk, actually I need simple example how to integrate

Comment: try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: What have you tried?? What are the issues? I'm sorry but this is a mess of a question

Comment: I tried many things, but all are failed. I want simple example with details

Comment: A simple example of what? The instructions for adding Firebase to an App are clearly laid out in the documentation, and examples of reading and writing data to/from Firebase are also provided.

Comment: @Jay  the instructions are c++ , but not for cocos2dx

Comment: Your iOS project can support several environments, so you could use Swift to handle the Firebase interface and pass the JSON data to your C++ libraries - there are also a number of bindings for Swift and cocos2dx. Isn't cocos2dx a C++ API? If so then have you tried [Adding Firebase to your C++ project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup#dependencies_1)?